# How to set focus on collectionView in swift 4?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate

Hello I have a `UICollectionView`. In a particular cell I have many views like `UserProfileView`, `ProductView`, `CommentBoxView` etc. In `CommentBoxView` there is a text view where the user can type and then post the comment. After posting the comment I want to focus that particular cell, from which cell user have posted the comment. For this I have used :

```
func indexPathForPreferredFocusedView(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> IndexPath? {
  return IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
}
```

I am testing with the hardcoded value but still it is not coming. Please any one help me regarding this matter.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps by "focus" you mean "scroll to." If you'd like to scroll to a cell, you should invoke

`collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, scrollPosition: .centeredVertically, animated: true)`

It may be useful to check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618046-scrolltoitem) for this function.

As far as I know, while `focus` is a central concept in tvOS development, in iOS, its main function is to drive accessibility experiences. As such, I don't think it will have the effect you're expecting.

Comment: where to write this code? after posting the comment?

Comment: sir how to pass indexPath in collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, scrollPosition: .centeredVertically, animated: true)?

Comment: Try something like `collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 2, section: 0), scrollPosition: .centeredVertically, animated: true)`.

Comment: @GoribDeveloper you need to write this code inside func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) method.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use:

```
self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: indexNumber, section: sectionNumber), at: .right, animated: false)
```

Comment: where to write this code? after posting the comment?

Comment: sir how to pass indexPath in collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, scrollPosition: .centeredVertically, animated: true)?

Comment: sure sir i will

Comment: actually sir i have a collectionView. In a particular cell I have many views like UserProfileView, ProductView, CommentBoxView etc. In CommentBoxView there is a textView where the user can type and then post the comment. After posting the comment I want to scroll that particular cell, from which cell user have posted the comment. I know that I have to use self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: indexNumber, section:       sectionNumber), at: .right, animated: false)

Comment: but it is not running

Comment: UserProfileView, ProductView, CommentBoxView etc
these all are made in a different cell?

Comment: i m using custom delegate for posting comment

Comment: you should use a different cell for this. Then you can identify which cell you need to focus or move to the selected index.

Comment: Using one cell, you can notify your CommentBoxView/ProductView etc. rest you need to do research on this.